# Python Vetiver model - use alternative prediction method

Tags: python, mlops, isolation-forest, vetiver

I'm trying to use [Vetiver](https://vetiver.rstudio.com/) to deploy an isolation forest model (for anomaly detection) to an API endpoint.

All is going well by adapting the example [here](https://vetiver.rstudio.com/get-started/).

However, when deployed, the endpoint uses the `model.predict()` method by default (which returns 1 for normal or -1 for anomaly).

I want the model to return a score between 0 and 1 as given by the `model.score_samples()` method.

Does anybody know how I can configure the Vetiver endpoint such that it uses `.score_samples()` rather than `.predict()` for scoring?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`vetiver.predict()` primarily acts as a router to an API endpoint, so it does not have to have the same behavior as `model.predict()`. You can overload what function `vetiver.predict()` uses on your model by [defining a custom handler](https://rstudio.github.io/vetiver-python/advancedusage/custom_handler.html).

In your case, an implementation might look something like below.

```
from vetiver.handlers.base import VetiverHandler

class ScoreSamplesHandler(VetiverHandler):
    def __init__(self, model, ptype_data):
        super().__init__(model, ptype_data)

    def handler_predict(self, input_data, check_ptype):
        """
        Define how to make predictions from your model
        """
        prediction = self.model.score_samples(input_data)
        
        return prediction
```

Initialize your custom handler and pass it into `VetiverModel()`.

```
custom_model = ScoreSamplesHandler(model, ptype_data)

VetiverModel(custom_model, "model_name")
```

Then, when you use the `vetiver.predict()` function, it will return the values for `model.score_samples()`, rather than `model.predict()`.